# Can you make a HTML element overflow-scroll ONLY vertically?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set a  to add a scroll-bar vertically but clip horizontally?

**EDIT** I see some mention on CSS3 in answers. Which browsers support this?

Answer (score 7):

```
html { overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; }
```

or `{ overflow-y:scroll; }`

Haven't tested but try it.

Comment: for IE8 you may also need -ms-overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: @gruntled Is overflow-x/y CSS3? I didn't see it when I was looking at overflow reference online originally.

Answer (score 3):

```
overflow: auto;     /* For CSS 2 user agents */
overflow-x: hidden; /* For UAs implementing the CSS 3 property */
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scrolling:

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

For vertical scrolling:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```